# How to best rebase my fork within PyCharm / IntelliJ

Tags: git, intellij-idea, pycharm

*I know several similar questions have been asked before, but I did not find an exact answer so far to the following problem.*

I'm collaborating on a GitHub project where I created a fork, and I'm using PyCharm to handle git. Whenever the master repository on GitHub pushes an update I choose 'rebase my github fork' and that seems to work well--my fork is updated to the main repository of the original project. However, to then update my files locally I'm unsure what is the best way to do. Simply choosing 'rebase' sometimes causes conflicts and even when I choose 'theirs' there is an error saying that the rebase has failed and it does not accept 'theirs'.  Am I doing something wrong with doing the rebase or what is the best way to handle this within PyCharm/IntelliJ?

After doing a 'refresh file status' from the VCS menu I sometimes then manage to do the rebase and everything seems up to date, but when I click again on rebase old commits that are already integrated into my current projects are popping up again and it asks me to pick/edit/skip the rebase. No matter what I do, they pop up again.

Any suggestions how to solve that are appreciated.

Comment: Can you give a more specific example? Are you saying that the rebase of `master` works but the rebase of a feature branch doesn't?

Comment: I'm a friend of the poster and observed the problem. Yes the rebase to the master works but then rebasing the local branch to the feature branch (I.e. GitHub fork) causes problems. The main issue I see is that a merge doesn't allow a conflict resolution with 'theirs' overwriting the local file that is in conflict. It just says that the rebase failed.